# Enable Federated Storage Engine in Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-storage, federated-storage-engine

How to enable Federated Storage engine/create federated tables in Google cloud sql?

I have already gone through the following post but i didnt really understand the solution.
[How do I create a Federated Table in Google Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986159/how-do-i-create-a-federated-table-in-google-cloud-sql)

Can someone give detailed step by step instruction about how to avhieve this?